# Saving a MemoryStream to Azure blob storage

Tags: c#, azure, memorystream, azure-blob-storage

I'm using the Infragistics report system to create reports as PDFs and save them to Azure Blob Storage but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I generate the report as a Report object without any problems. This object has a method called `Publish` which publishes the report to a stream in a specified file format, which in my case is PDF. When the code attempts to Upload from the stream, I get this error

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request

I have no idea what's causing this, the error message doesn't actually give me much to work on. I'm using local storage while I'm developing, this all seems to be working fine (I can store images without any problems). This is the method that's crashing out

```
public async Task<CloudBlockBlob> UploadAndSaveReportAsPDFToBlobAsync(Report report, EnumHelper.Reports reportName, string containerName)
{
    chpBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);
    string blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + Path.GetExtension(reportName.GetDescription());
    // Retrieve reference to a blob. 
    CloudBlockBlob reportBlob = chpBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        try
        {
            report.Publish(stream, FileFormat.PDF);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //
        }

        await reportBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
    }
    return reportBlob;
}
```

and this is a bit more of the error message

> Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException: Exception while executing function: Functions.ProcessQueueMessage ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\Common\Shared\Protocol\HttpResponseParsers.Common.cs:line 50
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlockBlob.<>c__DisplayClass42.<PutBlobImpl>b__41(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlockBlob.cs:line 2339
>      at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 299
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Anyone have any advice ?

I've updated my connection code on the constructor of my blob service, it now looks like this, but it still doesn't work and fiddler gives me this

CONNECT localhost:10000 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:10000

HTTP/1.1 200 Connection Established
FiddlerGateway: Direct
StartTime: 14:23:33.061
Connection: close
EndTime: 14:23:33.063
ClientToServerBytes: 125
ServerToClientBytes: 505

but its http, my connection specified https, Im still none the wiser

```
public BlobService()
    {
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("devstoreaccount1", "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==");
        var blobEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost.fiddler:10000");
        var queueEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost.fiddler:10001");
        var tableEndpoint = new Uri("https://localhost.fiddler:10002");
        var storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, blobEndpoint, queueEndpoint, tableEndpoint, null);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        chpBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("CHPReports");
        if (chpBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())
        {
            // Enable public access on the newly created "images" container.
            chpBlobContainer.SetPermissions(
                new BlobContainerPermissions
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Blob
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual filename? Also, are there any exceptions you are swallowing?

Comment: there is no way I can see to give it a file name as its supposed to be streamed directly to azure and taken out as a pdf at a later time.  I give it a unique name based on a GUID and its description.  There are no exceptions generated

Comment: how on earth is anyone meant to debug a process when the only error message is The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. ?.  Completely stumped here now

Comment: have you tried intercepting the call (https://zappysys.com/blog/how-to-use-fiddler-to-analyze-http-web-requests/) in Fiddler to analyze the response from Azure?

Comment: couldn't get fiddler to intercept localhost, I've googled solutions but they all seem to involve changing the url and I'm not sure that's possible when using azure locally, I don't control the url

Comment: edited my connection settings, but it made no difference

Comment: What is Publish doing? Perhaps you need to seek the stream back to the beginning?

Comment: can anyone help me out here ? I'm at a complete loss and cant move forward with this work.  I've been using this sample project 'ContosoAdsWebJobsSDK' to test uploading images to blob storage and it works perfectly.  Ive just duplicated the code for a memorystream, the connection code is the same.  Ive even tried reverting to v4.2.1.0 of the azure storage bsdk but it made no difference

Comment: publish puts the report into the stream and sets its format to pdf.  Ive tried  setting the stream seek to 0, but its not even getting that far now, its falling over in the constructor here  if (chpBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists())

Comment: what is container name? it will be bad request if invalid container name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You cannot use "CHPReports" as the container nam**e as the name must be lowercase.

Make sure the container name is [valid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata):

> A container name must be a valid DNS name, conforming to the following
>   naming rules: Container names must start with a letter or number, and
>   can contain only letters, numbers, and the dash (-) character. Every
>   dash (-) character must be immediately preceded and followed by a
>   letter or number; consecutive dashes are not permitted in container
>   names. All letters in a container name must be lowercase. Container
>   names must be from 3 through 63 characters long.

Comment: I just found that out ! put some error trapping around the CreateIfNotExists bit and I got this 'The specified resource name contains invalid characters.' then I remembered about the container name not being allowed uppercase characters

Comment: it works now, that's several hours of my life I wont get back !