# How to put a SQL Query Output as a excel file to Azure Data Lake in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, etl, azure-blob-storage

So basically, I want to get all this done in the SSIS package itself.

```
SQL Query output -> Convert to Excel file without any local files -> Upload to Azure Blob.
```

The "azure blob destination" has only the options for CSV, etc. But nothing to directly make it excel.

Converting it to excel require a local file as there excel file destination has only system file options.

If there is any way to get the output as excel file directly instead of CSV, then upload to Azure Blob.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/2029983)

Comment: Any specific reason from avoiding the use of local file system for excel destination task?

Comment: What is your actual reason for not wanting to create a local file? You might be able to do that in a different tool like Azure Automation but the only way to do it in SSIS is to use a script task, and even then I can't think of how you'd do it.

Comment: Hi Pradz101, if agree with my answer, you can mark it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: This https://www.ryadel.com/en/asp-net-generate-excel-files-programmatically-epplus-guide-tutorial-mvc-core/ shows how to generate an excel file as a `MemoryStream` This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45481567/saving-a-memorystream-to-azure-blob-storage shows how to save  a memory stream to blob storage. Stick them together and you should have your answer. When you do, please post the code as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. 
So, Basically, like Leon Yue said. There is no other way except locally.

The only way to go about it is, to use Azure File Store mounted to your local drive instead.

That way it thinks its sending it locally, However you use it to upload it directly to the Azure File Store of the Storage, then move to the blob storage.

Answer (score 0):

In SSIS, we can not put a SQL Query Output as a excel file to Azure Data Lake without using a local excel file.

Not only SSIS does't support do this, we can't find any other tools or scripts can achieve that.

Hope this helps.